# Arrow Java ListVector writeBatch and read get empty list

Tags: apache-arrow

I have a `ListVector` and value `[[1,2,3,4,5]]` in `VectorSchemaRoot` and I could see its value in IDEA.

I use following code to write the `VectorSchemaRoot` variable and get the byte array

```
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val writer = new ArrowStreamWriter(vectorSchemaRoot, null, out)
    writer.start()
    writer.writeBatch()
    writer.end()
    out.close()
    val byteArr = out.toByteArray
```

And read back

```
    val allocator = new RootAllocator(Int.MaxValue)
    val reader = new ArrowStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr), allocator)
    while (reader.loadNextBatch()) {
      val schemaRoot = reader.getVectorSchemaRoot
      schemaRoot
    }
```

The schema is correct, but the list is empty `[]`

However, I use other types of values, like char, bit, the result read from the `byteArr` is correct(non-empty).

How to fix the `ListVector` empty issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used just basic classes.

The `StructVector, ListVector` are complex classes, and according to my test, they do not bring speed or memory benefit over just using basic classes. And the documents for complex classes are very few.

Thus basic classes is recommended. And just use List of Fields to make the schema of them, could also get the structured vector.